# Editable WPF GridView Row

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

I am trying to create a databound WPF GridView whose rows can either be read-only or editable (by double-clicking or through a context menu). I would like for the row to return to a read-only state if any of its editable controls loses focus. The functionality I am looking for is very similar to [this example](http://blogs.msdn.com/atc_avalon_team/archive/2006/03/14/550934.aspx) but with an entire row being editted simultaneously (rather than a single cell).  Does anyone know how to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the ListView + GridView control il quite complex because this control "thinks in column" so you have to create a template for every column and switch the read-only template with edit template (for every cell).
I suggest you to take a look a the xceed DataGrid. It's free and it implements the edit functionality in a simpler way (you can find info here: http://xceed.com/Grid_WPF_Intro.html)

Comment: 800 dollars doesn't look free to me.

Comment: The post is quite old. Now xceed don't offer the grid for free anymore. Last year there was a free edition. Now you could use the WpfToolkit (http://wpf.codeplex.com/) that include a DataGrid.

Answer (score 7):

there is also the "official" wpf datagrid from microsoft at codeplex : http://www.codeplex.com/wpf

Answer (score 2):

The latest WPF has its own DataGrid.
http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question with an old answer, that this answer no longer works!
In .Net 6, for editing Grid-View in WPF, you must use the "CurrentCellChanged" event.

UI:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Margin="0,50,0,0" CurrentCellChanged="dataGrid_CurrentCellChanged"/>
```

Code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    List<myDataType>? tmp;
    //Add data
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = tmp;
}

private void dataGrid_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myDataType tmp = (sender as DataGrid).SelectedItem as myDataType ;
    if (tmp != null)
    {
       //Do your job here
       //tmp has edited data
    }
}
```